# Django Rest Framework model assigns a str to the primary key and a number to my str field in sqlite

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting my database table to contain a string as the ID (and primary key) while the actual string field contains the ID number, so those two fields seem to be swapped and I can't figure out why.

This is a basic Pokemon API for practise purposes, using Django 4.1.7, DRF 3.14 and sqlite as the DB. My models include: Card, Expansion and Type (fire, water, bug, ice, etc.)

**Type** is a tricky class, as it contains attributes that reference another Type object: *name, strong_against (Type), weak_against, resists, vulnerable_to*. Except for the type name (a string), all the other fields should reference another Type object (since one Pokemon type can be strong against other types, weak against other types, resists other types and is vulnerable to other types).

Type model:

```
class Type(models.Model):
    """Pokémon type"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False)
    strong_against = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name="strong_versus")
    weak_against = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name="weak_versus")
    resists = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name="resists")
    vulnerable = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name="vulnerable")

def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.name = name

def __str__(self):
    return f"Type name: {self.name}, Strong against: {self.strong_against}, Weak against: {self.weak_against}, Resists: {self.resists}, Vulnerable to: {self.vulnerable}"

def __repr__(self):
    return f"Type( ID: {self.pk}; NAME: {self.name})"
```

When trying to populate the "Type" database table I get weird results, where the type name field actually seems to contain the primary key value and the ID field contains the actual name, when it should be the other way around. I tried populating just one object manually using Django's admin page and also tried populating many objects at once using bulk_create(), and the results are the same. When I use `Type.objects.all()` to print the table contents this is how they're printed:

```
<QuerySet [Type( ID: Fire; NAME: 1)]>
```

Also, when trying to run `Type.objects.all().delete()` to clear the table records, I get "ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Fire'" ("Fire" is a type name, which seems to be inserted as the id instead of the actual name).

I also tried manually adding an "id" field like this:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Results are the same. Also tried removing the "*unique*" attribute of "`name`" in case that was somehow causing it to be used as the PK, but still same results.

Finally, I just decided to comment out all fields except "name", flush the DB, recreate it and test again:

```
class Type(models.Model):
    """Pokémon type"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

Again, same results. So even when the model is as simple as this, it still assigns 1 to the type name and then when I click on it to see details, I get "Type with ID “Fire” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?"

One more test I did was to change "Type" class name to "PokemonType" (just in case "Type" was colliding with some language or framework keyword). It didn't help.

The weird thing is that my **Expansion** model works ok and data is stored correctly in the same db.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after all the hassle I was able to find the culprit: it was my `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.name = name
```

It was causing the "name" argument to be assigned to the "id" field that Django auto-generates.

Since the table has other fields with many-to-many relationships with the same table, I wanted to be able to populate it with records containing only the name field and leaving everything else blank, eg: `Type(name="Fire")`, and then update them to create the relationships once there were records in the table.

I solved the problem by completely removing `__init__` and it still works when I instantiate my objects as `Type(name="Fire")`.